# TeamCity doesn't find csv files for unit tests

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, mstest

After writing unit tests using csv files to add multiple parameter combinations and checking them in, TeamCity which compiles and runs our tests, fails to find the CSV files which are in a data subfolder.  Is there any way TeamCity can be configured where to look for CSV files for MSTest?

Comment: How your tests are accessing the csv files. Is path to csv files mentioned in tests?

Comment: A relative path to the project directory was included in DeploymentItem.  After removing this it appears to work now in TeamCity.